# How to get days between closest date in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table (TABLE1) of user transactions like:

```
USER|DATE1
1111|2020-01-01
1111|2020-03-02
2222|2020-02-01
2222|2020-03-02
```

And I have a second table (TABLE2) of user transactions like:

```
USER|DATE2
1111|2020-01-05
1111|2020-01-06
1111|2020-03-07
1111|2020-03-08
2222|2020-02-07
2222|2020-02-30
2222|2020-03-30
```

How can I get a new field in TABLE1 that shows how many days passed since the most recent date in TABLE2.DATE2?

```
USER|DATE1|DAYS_PASSED
1111|2020-01-01|4
1111|2020-03-02|5
2222|2020-02-01|6
2222|2020-03-02|28
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.). Also tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: @stickybit - good point.  I inherently thought SQL Server, but that may not be the case ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lateral join is a reasonable approach.  In Snowflake, the syntax is:

```
select t1.*, t2.date, datediff(day, t1.date, t2.date) as days_passed
from table1 t1 cross join lateral
     (select min(t2.date) as date
      from table2 t2
      where t2.user = t1.user and
            t2.date > t1.date
     ) t2;
```

Comment: This works, but I did have to flip things around a bit since I want the date delta between the most recent date of t1 and the closest (min) of t2. So, for future people viewing this answer I had to use t2.date >= t1.date, datediff(day, t1.date, t2.date), and min(t2.date)

Comment: @MarkMcGown . . . I fixed the query for the logic you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [USER], DATE1,
ISNULL(DATEDIFF(day, DATE1, 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 t2.DATE2
    FROM TABLE2 t2
    WHERE t2.USER = t1.USER
    AND t2.DATE2 > t1.DATE1
    ORDER BY t2.DATE2 ASC
)), 0) AS [DAYS_PASSED]
FROM TABLE1 t1
```

Although, one point - if the same date exists between TABLE1 and TABLE2, how do you want to handle that?  My example above would ignore same date match and then find the next one after.  However, if you want to return zero (0) if there's a same date match, then change

```
t2.DATE2 > t1.DATE1
```

to be

```
t2.DATE2 >= t1.DATE1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `outer apply` to make the correlation and aggregate to a single date to compare. The `date` function is Sqlserver - if your database is different (you haven't tagged it) you should easily be able to use equivalent syntax.

This should have a performance advantage as it won't require a `TopN sort` - if that's relevant to the size of data or not.

```
select t1.[USER], t1.DATE1, DateDiff(day, t1.DATE1, t2.DATE2) Days_Passed
from TABLE1 t1
outer apply (
    select [USER], Min(Date2) DATE2
    from TABLE2 t2
    where t2.[USER] = t1.[USER] and t2.DATE2>= t1.DATE1
    group by t2.[USER]
)t2
```